# Is this the correct way to add a second activity to my manifest.xml file

Tags: android

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.androidgames"
       android:versionCode="1"
       android:versionName="1.0">
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

     <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
         <activity android:name=".AndroidBasicsStarter" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>

         //New Activity        
         <activty android:label="Life Cycle Test"
                  android:name=".LifeCycleTest"
                  android.configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />

     </application>
 </manifest>
```

Comment: Other than the fact that you probably should have some intent-filters I think that's it.

Comment: I also see two typos ... "<activity ...>" is spelled wrong and it should be "android:configChanges= ..." Just in case you're asking because you can't get it to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks good, but consider moving the label to the strings resource file :)

In this case your activity should match a LifeCycleTest class in the root of your package (com.androidgames).

Comment: Great. And I did create a class called LifeCycleTest. However, when I click on the activity in the android emulator it says "The application Starter (process com.androidgames) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"

Comment: Make sure the new class has a onCreate() if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's about the sum of it.